# Nestled API calls in JavaScript Axios, returning the right promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise, redux-thunk

I am trying to post data to my API using axios. I need to request and send a XSFR-token along with the request. I am using React, Redux, Thunk and Axios. 
I need to have this handled as a promise inside the React component itself. It is now but it doesn't respond in the desired way. It always resolves the promise, even if the post failed, as long a the token request succeeded.

My call to start this in my React component is at the bottom, it gives me yes even if the axios call failed on the post and I do get the error message from the catch on the second call. If I put a Promise.reject() in there it also gets sent but uncaught because a promise has already been returned, I think.

I tried wrapping the entire thing in a return Promise.all([getToken()...]). It works but behaves exactly the same and still gives me a resolve from the success at receiving the token and disregards the second axios call.

Actions:

```
export function Post(data) {

  return (dispatch) => {
    return getToken('csfr')
      .then(response => {
         return axios.post( '/post', {
           request: data,
           token: response,
           apitoken: 'apikey',
         })
         .then(response => {
           dispatch({type: 'POST', payload: response});
         })
         .catch(error => {
           dispatch(errorPopup({visible: true, message: error}));
           throw error;
         });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(errorPopup({visible: true, message: error}));
      });

  };
}


export function getToken(tokentype) {
   return axios.post( '/token/' + tokentype, {
     apitoken: 'apikey',
   })
   .then()
   .catch(error => {
     throw error;
   });
}
```

React component (Post action is bound to props using Redux):

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.Post(this.state.data)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('yes')
   })
   .catch(() => {
     console.log('no')
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to use this *Action Creator* to *dispatch* an action based upon the result of a number of previous async requests, you should not be using the *return* keyword to return the Promise from the async operations.

Remove the inner `return` keyword and allow the `.then` and `.catch` to *dispatch* your action.

Relatedly, I recommend you investigate the use of *Async/Await*. This code construct (and interpretation difficulty) is exactly why Async/Await was put into the language.

The following code (modified to meet your architecture) will satisfy your use case. Please note that I took liberties everywhere by mocking methods etc. For instance, like `fetch()`, `axios` methods return a promise. I think you'll get the gist. Please let me know if you have questions.

```
async function getToken(tokentype) {
  try {
    return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  };
}

function dispatch(data) {
  console.log(data);
}



function Post(data) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      let token = await getToken('csfr');
      let post = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
      dispatch({
        type: 'POST',
        payload: post
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch('error: ' + error);
      throw error;
    };
  }
}

let attempt = Post('This is a test');
attempt().then(() => {
  console.log('Completed Post');
})
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0n6to6Lm/21/

If you want to set up your architecture in the [React Editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I'll be happy to help make it work.

Comment: Yes that is what I did from the beginning, but this particular POST is a special case operation that should be fired only once automatically in just this component. The component should be closed if it succeeds and allow manual retry with different data if not.
This is why I wanted to catch the promise inside the component and use the local state (while still using the redux store error display i have). 
But it is maybe better to setup a special case in the redux store for this as well?

Comment: Sounds like a special case in the store may be the way. Watch a state change and react to that. You know, a middleware.

Comment: @HåkanKA - Please take look at my revised answer. It should meet your needs with the right modifications to match your architecture.

Comment: Thank you that was very enlightening and I got it to work. 
Except for the dispatches, it always returns reject if I try to use the dispatch that is sent automatically. 
Maybe manually import the store if dispatch is really needed in there?

But I think it might just be confusing to mix dispatches into this action anyway? I can just dispatch when I set the local state for the one time action handling inside the then() and catch() in the component should be cleaner?  getToken() still appears to still be re-usable in other more pure redux-thunk action creators too. Thank you!

Comment: REF the dispatch not working (just in case): did you forget to put a reference to dispatch back into the _action creator_? This code: `return async () => {` needs to be like this for React/Redux/Thunk: `return async (dispatch) => {`.

Comment: Tried it again now and dispatch inside of this answer like that also works as expected. I am not sure why that produced a strange behavior yesterday.